# Как разграничить права токенов Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, role, laravel-sanctum

В моем приложении Laravel 10 я использую пакет [Spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction) для ролей и [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum) для авторизации.

Во время авторизации я создаю токен доступа с помощью Sanctum, передавая параметру `abilities` массив ролей, созданных Spatie во время регистрации:

```
$user->createToken($user->name, [
    $user->getRoleNames()->toArray()
])->plainTextToken;
```

По умолчанию у пользователей могут быть только две роли: `user` или `admin`.

При попытке обновить информацию другого пользователя (не того, которому был выдан токен доступа) Я получаю исключение `AuthenticationException` даже на уровне маршрута, прежде чем добраться до контроллеров.

Мои роуты выглядят так:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('users', UserController::class);
});
```

Где и как можно (нужно) правильно настроить разрешения, чтобы пользователи с ролью `user` имели доступ только к получению информации и редактированию самих себя, а пользователи с ролью `admin` также имели доступ и к редактированию всех пользователей?

Comment: Как же вы усложняете себе жизнь с этими `abilities`. Почему вы не хотите использовать политики? Если хотите, могу позже написать полноценный пример.

Comment: @Dinario да, буду благодарен! Не работал с ними ранее, к сожалению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажу пример, как это делается с помощью политик.

Если учитывать, что админ может все. То сразу определяем это в провайдере:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
            return $user->hasRole('admin') ? true : null;
        });
    }
}
```

Можно использовать любые ваши проверки. В данном случае проверяется есть ли у пользователя роль `admin`. Подробнее про [Gate::before](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks).

Далее создаем саму политику. Покажу общий пример, все остальное делается по аналогии.

```
class UserPolicy
{
    public function update(User $user, User $object): bool
    {
        return $user->id === $object->id;
    }
}
```

`$user` - это текущий авторизованный пользователь. Падает сюда автоматически. `$object` - объект, над которым мы совершаем действие. Админа мы тут никак не проверяем, т.к. до этого мы разрешили ему делать все. Подробнее про [политики](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#writing-policies). Если у вас не включено автоматическое обнаружение политик, вам нужно зарегистрировать их вручную. По умолчанию включено.

Далее нужно авторизовать действие. Например, можно так:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function update(User $user)
    {
       $this->authorize('update', $user);
       
       //Ваша логика
    }
}
```

Тут мы вызываем метод `update` нашей политики, передавая туда наш объект. Другие варианты авторизаций описаны [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies)

Политика очень удобная вещь для вынесения логики авторизации.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный пример! Для остальных добавлю пару слов про еще одну удобную фишку - у базового контроллера есть трейт `AuthorizesRequests`. Из него в конструкторе любого дочернего контроллера можно вызвать метод `$this->authorizeResource`, передав в него модель, к которой привязана та или иная политика. Это уберет необходимость прописывать в каждом методе авторизацию действий через `$this->authorize`. Вычитал на той же странице доки: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.

Исправил присвоение полю `abilities`, у меня был вложенный массив, вместо обычного:

```
$user->createToken(
    $user->name,
    $user->getRoleNames()->toArray() // здесь будет ["user"] или ["admin"]
)->plainTextToken;
```

В метод обновления добавил проверку на наличие роли администратора, если идентификатор обновляемого пользователя отличается от пользователя, который авторизован:

```
if (!$updateRequest->user()->id != $id &&
    !$updateRequest->user()->tokenCan('admin')
) {
    throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```

Comment: `идентификатор обновляемого пользователя отличается от пользователя, который авторизован` звучит очень странно, сравнивают обычно id авторизованного и id автора

Comment: @InDevX, безусловно, если речь идет о блоге, например. У меня проблема возникла на моменте обновления информации пользователя, если я буду обновлять материалы, которые создавали пользователи – да, я буду проверять ID автора.

Comment: Блог это древность, теперь везде одни магазины. `обновления информации пользователя` c этим уже не звучит так странно, а то пользователи какие-то обновляемые)

Comment: Что будет, если в будущем у вас появится еще одна роль? И пользователь перейдет на эту роль?

Comment: @Dinario например? Если появится еще одна административная роль? Подозреваю, что придется добавлять ее везде, где был завязан `admin`, а это не есть хорошо, пока не знаю как этого можно избежать